# why input text created from Jquery html() can't be used in $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, output

I have created a shopping cart using Jquery. and the product list is displayed using html() function.but when I put my  fields inside that output they are not accessible in $_POST.

***I am new to stack sorry if I made any mistake while asking this question***

This is my Jquery that generate Jquery output.Data is successfully displayed:(storage2.js)

```
    var shoppingCart = (function() {
      // =============================
      // Private methods and propeties
      // =============================
      cart = [];

      // Constructor
      function Item(name, price,image,id, seller, count) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.image = image;
        this.id = id;
        this.seller = seller;
        this.count = count;
      }

      // Save cart
      function saveCart() {
        sessionStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(cart));
      }

        // Load cart
      function loadCart() {
        cart = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
      }
      if (sessionStorage.getItem("shoppingCart") !== null) {
        loadCart();
      }


      // =============================
      // Public methods and propeties
      // =============================
      var obj = {};

      // Add to cart
      obj.addItemToCart = function(name, price,image,id, seller, count) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart[item].count ++;
            saveCart();
            return;
          }
        }
        var item = new Item(name, price,image,id, seller, count);
        cart.push(item);
        saveCart();
      };

      // Set count from item
      obj.setCountForItem = function(name, count) {
        for(var i in cart) {
          if (cart[i].name === name) {
            cart[i].count = count;
            break;
          }
        }
      };

      // Remove item from cart
      obj.removeItemFromCart = function(name) {
          for(var item in cart) {
            if(cart[item].name === name) {
              cart[item].count --;
              if(cart[item].count === 0) {
                cart.splice(item, 1);
              }
              break;
            }
        }
        saveCart();
      };

      // Remove all items from cart
      obj.removeItemFromCartAll = function(name) {
        for(var item in cart) {
          if(cart[item].name === name) {
            cart.splice(item, 1);
            break;
          }
        }
        saveCart();
      };

      // Clear cart
      obj.clearCart = function() {
        cart = [];
        saveCart();
      };

      // Count cart
      obj.totalCount = function() {
        var totalCount = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCount += cart[item].count;
        }
        return totalCount;
      };

      // Total cart
      obj.totalCart = function() {
        var totalCart = 0;
        for(var item in cart) {
          totalCart += cart[item].price * cart[item].count;
        }
        return Number(totalCart.toFixed(2));
      };

      // List cart
      obj.listCart = function() {
        var cartCopy = [];
        for(i in cart) {
          item = cart[i];
          itemCopy = {};
          for(p in item) {
            itemCopy[p] = item[p];

          }
          itemCopy.total = Number(item.price * item.count).toFixed(2);
          cartCopy.push(itemCopy);
        }
        return cartCopy;
      };

      // cart : Array
      // Item : Object/Class
      // addItemToCart : Function
      // removeItemFromCart : Function
      // removeItemFromCartAll : Function
      // clearCart : Function
      // countCart : Function
      // totalCart : Function
      // listCart : Function
      // saveCart : Function
      // loadCart : Function
      return obj;
    })();


    // *****************************************
    // Triggers / Events
    // *****************************************


    // Clear items
    $('.clear-cart').click(function() {
      shoppingCart.clearCart();
      displayCart2();
    });


    function displayCart2() {
      var cartArray = shoppingCart.listCart();
      var total = shoppingCart.totalCart();
      var grand = total + 50;
      var output = "";
      for(var i in cartArray) {
        output += "<input type='hidden' name='prdID[]' value='" + cartArray[i].name + "'>"
          +  "<input type='hidden' name='price[]' value='" + cartArray[i].price + "'>"
          +  "<input type='hidden' name='qty[]' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "'>"
          + "<tr>"
          + "<td class='name-pr' style='width:80px;text-align:center'> <img src='../../img/Uploads/subCat/" + cartArray[i].image + "' style='width:60px;height:50px'> </td>"
          +  "<td class='name-pr'>" + cartArray[i].id + "</td>"
          +  "<td class='name-pr'>" + cartArray[i].seller + "</td>"
          +  "<td class='quantity-box' style='text-align:center;'><input style='background-color:transparent;border-color:#1f7a1f !important' type='number'  data-name='" + cartArray[i].name + "' value='" + cartArray[i].count + "' min='1'  class='item-count qtynumber'></td>"
          +  "<td class='price-pr' style='text-align:right'><p>Rs." + cartArray[i].total + "</p></td>"
          +  "<td class='remove-pr'><button class='delete-item btn btn-danger mbxy' data-name=" + cartArray[i].name + ">x</button></td>"
          +  "</tr>";
        }
        var output2 = "<input type='text' name='total' value='"+ total +"'>";

      $('.show-cart2').html(output);
      $('.show-total').html(output2);
      $('.grand').html(grand);
      $('.total-cart2').html(shoppingCart.totalCart());
      $('.total-count2').html(shoppingCart.totalCount());
    }

    // Delete item button top

    $('.show-cart2').on("click", ".delete-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCartAll(name);
      displayCart2();
    });


    // -1
    $('.show-cart2').on("click", ".minus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      shoppingCart.removeItemFromCart(name);
      displayCart2();
    });

    // +1
    $('.show-cart2').on("click", ".plus-item", function(event) {
      var name = $(this).data('name');
      shoppingCart.addItemToCart(name);
      displayCart2();
    });

    // Item count input
    $('.show-cart2').on("change", ".item-count", function(event) {
       var name = $(this).data('name');
       var count = Number($(this).val());
      shoppingCart.setCountForItem(name, count);
      displayCart2();
    });


    displayCart2();
```

this is the code part in php to get the value: (cart.php)

```
        function checkout(){
      if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
        if (isset($_POST['placeorder'])) {


          foreach ($_POST['prdID'] as $id => $productid) {
            $prdID    = $_POST['prdID'];
            $price   = $_POST['price'];
            $qty      = $_POST['qty'];

            
            echo $prdID;
            echo $price;
            echo $qty;

          }

        }
      }
    }
```

Only problem here is the php $_POST does not get the   fields.

php file with the table output and form

```
        <body style="user-select: none;">
        <!-- Start Main Top -->
        <div class="main-top" style="background-color:#339966;">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Main Top -->


        <!-- Start Main Top -->
        <header class="main-header">
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light navbar-default bootsnav" style="height:70px !important;">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-menu" aria-controls="navbars-rs-food" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                    </button>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php"><img src="../../img/mylogo2.png" class="logo" alt="logo" style="height:70px; width:180px;padding-bottom:5px"></a>
                    </div>
                    <!-- End Header Navigation -->

                    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-menu" style="background-color:#F8F9FA !important;">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto" data-in="fadeInDown" data-out="fadeOutUp">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="about.php">About Us</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="shop.php">Shop</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="contactus.php">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->

                    <?php include("header.php"); ?>

            </nav>
        </header>


        <!-- Start All Title Box -->
        <div class="all-title-box" style="background-image:url('images/103.jpg')">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12" style="height:60px;">
                        <h2 style="color:#262626">Shopping Cart</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



        <!-- Start Cart  -->
        <div class="cart-box-main">
            <div class="container">


              <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                      <div class="card">
                          <div class="card-img"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/sucess2.jpg"> </div>
                          <div class="card-title">
                              <p style="color:#339966">Success!</p>
                          </div>
                          <div class="card-text" >
                              <p style="font-size:18px !important;color:#206040">Thank You <br>Your Order will be ready..</p>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal2" role="dialog">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-img"> <img class="img-fluid" src="images/err.jpg"> </div>
                        <div class="card-title">
                            <p style="color:#cc0000">Error !</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-text" >
                            <p style="font-size:18px !important;color:#990000">Something went Wrong <br>Please Try Again..</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>

              <h2 class="noo-sh-title-top" style="font-size:18px;">Products in my Cart</h2><br>
              <?php checkout();  ?>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-11" >
                        <div class="table-main">
                            <table class="table">
                                <thead><form  method="post">
                                    <tr>
                                        <th style="text-align:center">I</th>
                                        <th>Product Name</th>
                                        <th>Seller</th>
                                        <th style="text-align:center;">Quantity</th>
                                        <th style="text-align:right;">Price</th>
                                        <th style="text-align:center;">Remove</th>
                                    </tr>

                                </thead>

                                <tbody class="show-cart2">
                                         <!--output is adding to here-->
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="row my-5">
                    <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12">
                        <div class="order-box">
                            <h3>Order summary</h3>
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <h4>Sub Total</h4>
                                <div class="ml-auto font-weight-bold "> Rs. <span class="total-cart2"></span>.00</div>
                                <div class="show-total"> </div>

                            </div>
                            <div class="d-flex">
                                <h4>Service Charge</h4>
                                <div class="ml-auto font-weight-bold"> Rs. 50.00 </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                            <div class="d-flex gr-total">
                                <h5>Grand Total</h5>
                                <div class="ml-auto h5" > Rs. <span class="grand"></span>.00 </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr> </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-lg-1 col-sm-12"></div>

                    <div class="col-lg-7 col-sm-12" style="width:80%;">
                      <div class="checkout-address">
                          <div class="title-left">
                              <h3>Place the Order</h3>
                          </div>
                              <div class="row">
                                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                      <label for="firstName"> <span style="color:red">*</span> Customer Name</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName" name="fname"  required >
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="col-md-6 mb-3">
                                      <label for="lastName"><span style="color:red">*</span> Contact Number</label>
                                      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" pattern="[0-9]{10}" name="contact"  required min="10" maxlength="10"  required>
                                    </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="mb-3">
                                  <label for="email"><span style="color:red">*</span> Email Address</label>
                                  <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email"  required name="email">
                              </div>

                              <hr class="mb-4">

                              <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-4">
                                  <div class="title"><span style="color:red">*</span> Order Date</div>
                                  <div class="d-block my-3">
                                    <div class="form-check" style="display:inline;padding-right:15px;">
                                        <input id="credit" name="schDate" value="Today" type="radio" class="form-check-input" checked required >
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="credit" >Today</label>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-check" style="display:inline">
                                        <input id="debit" name="schDate" value="Tommorow" type="radio" class="form-check-input" required>
                                        <label class="form-check-label" for="debit" >Tommorow</label>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
                                    <label for="state"><span style="color:red">*</span> Time</label>
                                    <select class="wide w-100" id="state" required name="time">
                                        <option value="" >Choose...</option>
                                        <option value="Morning" >Morning (9-12)</option>
                                        <option value="Evenning" >Evenning (12-6)</option>
                                        <option value="Night" >Afternoon (6-8)</option>
                                     </select>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                              <div class="row">
                                <button type="input" name="placeorder" class="ml-auto btn hvr-hover" style="float:right;color:white;">Place Order</button>
                              </div>
                          </form>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- End Cart -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/storage2.js"></script>

        <!-- Start Footer  -->
        <?php include("footer.php"); ?>
    </body>
```

Comment: The HTML being generated above is invalid - you cannot have `input` elements in the middle of a `table` like that - they need to be in a `td`

Comment: I have another    var output2 = "<input type='text' name='total' value='"+ total +"'>";  which will not be included in a table. this also has the same issue. php says this is a undefined index

Comment: Please add ***all*** the relevant code rather than just small pieces which do not build the correct picture

Comment: Your HTML markup is invalid - the FORM must either wholly contain the table or it must be wholly contained within a single table-cell element. So `<thead><form  method="post">` is clearly invalid and the form does not appear to be closed - at least not in the correct place. It is important that elements are nested correctly - there are rules and an incorrect nesting can cause all sorts of issues

Comment: 53 opening `<div>` tags and 52 closing `</div>` tags... and many more errors. Run your rendered HTML (ie: browser source code) through the [W3CValidator](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Comment: Thank you very much.. I am learning all by myself. Really appreciate your help...

Comment: putting <form> outside the <thead> worked. Thank you for saving my day...

Answer (score 0):

`$_POST` will only get the value if you them either in form submit or explicitly passing the values if making AJAX call.

You have not provided the full HTML, but I guess the fields are outside the `<form>` element.

Comment: these are inside the <form> . And when I put a hardcoded <input type='hidden' name='price[]' value='val'> it is working

Comment: @IshuHerath _"these are inside the <form>"_ - they might _not_ be, after the browser has applied error correction to try and parse your invalid HTML. (You should be able to verify this via the DOM inspector though.)

Comment: I have updated the question with the full html php and js codes